# Ayurveda is a part of which of the four veda?

Tags: vedas, ayurveda

Is there a part of veda which has been categorized as aayurveda. I want to find, read and investigate the shlokas which give direct advice on health and medicinal cure.

I wanted to understand and learn the ancient medical practices, medicines and the health benefits described about the practices of yoga. And even possibly have some secrets about the inner spiritual workings of the human body.